# Python No module named site

Tags: python

I wanted to execute the yumdownloader command inside my python program to download the rpm of php.

```
cmd1='yumdownloader --resolve --destdir=/tmp/repo php
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=proc1.communicate()
```

I have got the famous "No module named site" problem.

```
yumdownloader --resolve --destdir=/tmp/tmpe86CxN vim
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

I looked at other sites and most said that the problem comes from multi installation of python. But what should I do? Anyone has an idea? Thanks :)

Comment: On my machine this error in 99% of all cases means that I forgot to set the right interpreter for the python project in my IDE.

Comment: You are right. After recheck the PATH, the problem is solved. Thanks.